# Why do I get error and the query not executing in SQLlite

Tags: sqlite

why do I get error when executing the following:

INSERT INTO AnniversaryAttendees
(CustomerID, PartySize)
VALUES
((SELECT CustomerID FROM Customers WHERE Email="xyz@gmail.com"),
("4");

Error while executing SQL query on database 'restaurant': incomplete input

Comment: Remove the opening parenthesis before `"4"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of the extra ( before "4? Try:

```
INSERT INTO AnniversaryAttendees (CustomerID, PartySize) VALUES ((SELECT CustomerID FROM Customers WHERE Email="xyz@gmail.com"), "4");
```